# Telegram, Java: upload file to send in sendAnimation

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, telegram, telegram-bot

There's a method in [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendanimation) called `sendAnimation`. There are two obligatory paramteres: `chat_id` and `animation`. `animation`'s descriptio is this:

> **Type**: InputFile or String
>
> **Description**: Animation to send. Pass a file_id as String to send an animation that
>   exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a
>   String for Telegram to get an animation from the Internet, or upload a
>   new animation using multipart/form-data. More info on Sending Files »

I have a local `.gif` file that I want to send. So it looks like I need to use that `multipart/form-data` method. I don't understand what that method is. I checked out the `InputFile` type's description:

> **InputFile** This object represents the contents of a file to be
>   uploaded. Must be posted using multipart/form-data in the usual way
>   that files are uploaded via the browser.

Again, they write about that `multipart/form-data` thing, but don't write what exactly that is.

I thought maybe I could upload a file using `sendDocument` method, but the uploaded document must be of type `InputFile` as well.

How do I make the `InputFile` object out of my local `.gif`? I can convert it to Java's `InputStream`, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply multipart/form-data is just an encryption type for the sent data there are three types of encryption in forms:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

for more info about multipart/form-data check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/7366850)

I don't know what is the type of your GIF object in java but let us consider it a binary file then you would simply post this text as follows using POST request:

```
String url = "uploading url";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String param = "value";
File binaryFile = new File("/path/to/file.bin");
String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.
String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.

URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

try {
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);
     // Send binary file.
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"binaryFile\"; filename=\"" + binaryFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(binaryFile.getName())).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
    writer.append(CRLF).flush();
    Files.copy(binaryFile.toPath(), output);
    output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
    writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.

    // End of multipart/form-data.
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
}

// Request is lazily fired whenever you need to obtain information about response.
int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode); // Should be 200
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure though to which address to send the gif. Meaning what should be the value of the `url` variable. Some telegram server? But which one?

Comment: I figured that bit out. The address is `...sendAnimation`. I've found a shorter version though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140570/how-to-send-multipart-post-request-using-httpurlconnection-in-java. Is your version faster or do you think it's OK to use the other one?