# HttpURLConnection: writing into OutputStream, get response

Tags: java, http, request, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37722485/4759176) answer to write into a `HttpURLConnection`. It works fine and I close the stream and the connection:

```
 MultipartEntityBuilder mb = 
 MultipartEntityBuilder.create();//org.apache.http.entity.mime
 mb.addTextBody("foo", "bar");
 mb.addBinaryBody("bin", new File("testFilePath"));
 org.apache.http.HttpEntity e = mb.build();

 URLConnection conn = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/app").openConnection();
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 conn.addRequestProperty(e.getContentType().getName(), 
 e.getContentType().getValue());//header "Content-Type"...
 conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
 String.valueOf(e.getContentLength()));
 OutputStream fout = conn.getOutputStream();
 e.writeTo(fout);//write multi part data...
 fout.close();
 conn.getInputStream().close();//output of remote url
```

just fine. However, I would like to know the server's response (json). How would I do that? I tried using:

```
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
input.close();
```

But I get a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error.

In the past I've only used the `conn.connect()` method and then the `conn.getInputStream()` and it worked fine. Why it doesn't now? How do I fix that error?

Comment: the delimiter is `\\A` if I recall correctly

Comment: @Benjamin Urquhart `\\Z` worked fine for me so far. I've changed it to `\\A`, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Use a StringBuilder to build the string instead I guess. It's not a one-liner, but it should work.

Comment: @Benjamin Urquhart But why wouldn't the Scanner work in this case when it works in the `.connect()` case?

Comment: I'm not sure. Sorry.